# WebHook Tags for OMS

Tags: azure, webhooks

I have a Webhook setup in the OMS(Microsoft Operation Management Suite). I want some Tags(e.g. #alertrulename,#searchinterval etc).

I have googled & got 6-7 tags which are helpful to trigger the OMS alert specific details. Is there any tag which can send the Log details of the query?

i.e. **the Queered Log**.

Reference--> [MSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-webhooks)

Answer (score 0):

[These are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-actions#webhook-actions) all the actions available to the webhook:

```
AlertRuleName
AlertThresholdOperator
AlertThresholdValue
LinkToSearchResults
ResultCount
SearchIntervalEndtimeUtc
SearchIntervalInSeconds
SearchIntervalStartTimeUtc
SearchQuery
SearchResults
WorkspaceID
```

Also, if your workspace is upgraded take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-alerts-actions#sample-payload).

Comment: My target is to fetch the Search result. but
IncludeSearchResults and have tried in many different ways, in my response json all I see is {"IncludeSearchResults":true} ..

it don't return the search result. It only returns the Search query which is of no use.

Comment: can Someone help here?

Answer (score 0):

These all webhook variables need to be in certain format.

> {"AlertName":"#alertrulename", "IncludeSearchResults":true}

Don't use any Sub-node (child node) i.e.

> {"Data": {"AlertName":"#alertrulename", "IncludeSearchResults":true }}

**NB:-** Don't click on TestWebhook, it won't return any Logs, wit for the Timely trigger according to the schedule you have given to fire.